# i want to split the value Calls to check with values not 24|322||Calls. how do i do that?

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-show="TypeData.CallCenter_Type.value=='24|322||Calls'">
   <input type="button"/>
</div>
```

now i only want Calls to check in value
how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **[`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)**

```
ng-show="TypeData.CallCenter_Type.value.indexOf('Calls')>-1"
```

`indexOf` will return `-1` if not found.